# Would it be off topic to promote the "topic challenge" here?

Tags: discussion

I am referring to [this](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/457/topic-challenges-iii-return-of-the-topic) at the CS Ed site?

Comment: Probably best to summarize here what topic challenges are, to make this question somewhat self-contained.